# Database design for products with multiple features

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, laravel-5

Suppose you are designing a searchable price database for a local pricelist, and have a situation like the following:

**Example:**

Searching for a product "Businesscard". So "Businesscard" is the main product. But when you look into it, you want to see different kind of grams like 125 Grams and 250 Grams. And different kind of features like folded and non-folded. The prices for 125 Grams and 250 grams are different. And also they have different quantity.

So I'm building a webapplication where colleagues can login, add products and search products. But I want to build it as simple as possible.

**Information needed to add product:**

Product_name, Product_description, Product_category (so far I got this working, these are the main information, does not change).

*I'm sorry, cant even explain it correctly, so i will sketch whats in my mind, something like this:*

[This is what information i need and how I want to display it when searched (below the basic main information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVIwU.png)

For this webapplication I use **Laravel** >5.0 and mySQL DB

Comment: Can you show what you've come up with / tried so far to achieve what you want.

Comment: Can't you just have a column `gram`, a column `price` and a column `quality`? You could have that as a `product_category`

Comment: Yes you can, look at my answer. However it's up to you to print it correctly and keep the data the same or certain fields will be empty.

Comment: @DylanWijnen I have not coded that part yet because I have to 'dream' it first :) But I will show some after I tried your solution. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 2):

From this data model you'll be able to extract all the data you need.

```
- Product
    - Product_Type  : "000102", //Main Article Nr
    - Product_Nr    : "001", //Added Article Nr
    - Product_Name  : "Businesscard Folded",

    - Product_Type  : "000102",
    - Product_Nr    : "002",
    - Product_Name  : "Businesscard Non-Folded",


- Product_Property
    - Product_Nr*, //Relation to Product.
    - Property_Name : "100gr",
    - Quantity : 100, //You could also make this a relation and notworry about invalid quantities same goes for Property_Names
    - Cost: 10
```

Comment: I will try this, I suppose it will work though! Thank you for your answer. I will let it know if it worked for me or not :)

Comment: I think the Product_Nr of the "Businesscard Non-Folder" should be different then "Businesscard Folded" ?

Comment: Could you help me set up the form? Because I cant figure it out really. Got stuck at asking for product properties. And I dont understand how to get the product article nr? A different form?

Comment: @A.C.E Please make an edit to you're question or open another question. For help and explain what you need help with. What have you tried so far. You say you're using laravel how have you setup you're models etc.